# React microfrontend with Module Federation

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I consider to create microfrontend with Webpack 5 Module Federation as described on https://indepth.dev/posts/1173/webpack-5-module-federation-a-game-changer-in-javascript-architecture.

Has anyone experience with Webpack 5 Module Federation? If yes, could you please share your experience?

Can I use it with Create a New React App tool? When I create an app with Create a New React App, I can not see any webpack.config.js file.

Comment: take a look at this, there is a working webpack 5 branch for react-scripts now,[https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10961](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/10961).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different questions, if you are asking how to add `webpack module federation` in CRA, you can use something called [react-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired)

You can override CRA webpack default config like below.

```
/* config-overrides.js */

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  //do stuff with the webpack config...
  return config;
}
```

Comment: This is too generic. How will you actually use Module federation with rewired? I couldn't see any plugin that does the job as I am writing in April 2021 !! If I am wrong please correct me. I would love to use this feature with CRA.

Comment: would agree, trying to use both craaco and react-rewired as of April 2021 there are too many conflicts within the webpack configuration / webpack dev server. Most webpack configurations can be sorted out but the dev server and start script don't allow for it to function properly

Answer (score 1):

You can run the script `react-scripts eject` to stop hiding what it's got installed under the hood, including `webpack` config.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample POC for Microfrontends in React with Module Federation 5
https://github.com/sarat9/microfrontends

Expose and import the modules using the plugin 'ModuleFederationPlugin' in the shared environments.

Answer (score 1):

New version of `create-react-app` uses webpack 5 so it support module federation. I customize my webpack configuration using [react-app-rewired](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired).
So, I add module federation in `config-overrides.js` like:

```
/* config-overrides.js */
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
const packageJSON = require('./package.json');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    //do stuff with the webpack config...
    
    // const publicPath = `http://localhost:${8081}/`;
    if(env === 'development') {
        config.output.publicPath = `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/`;
    } else {
        config.output.filename = '[name].[contenthash].js';
        config.output.publicPath = '/';
    }

    config.plugins.push(
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'info',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
                './InfoApp': './src/bootstrap'
            },
            shared: packageJSON.dependencies
        })
    )
    return config;
}
```

You see its more less code and we are still using `create-react-app` under the hood.

Here is `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "info",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I am also doing something like this but facing , "However it throws an error saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')".

Comment: Do u want to share your code structure of package .json file pls

Comment: Sure I have edited the question and include my package.json @ProblemSolver

Comment: @ProblemSolver Its very simple just create your create-react-app install react-app-rewired and using this over-ride configuration in config-overrides.js

Answer (score 0):

The only way that seems to work is to 'eject' CRA. But the problem is it is now on webpack 4 and there are a lot of breaking changes to make it work with version 5. Struggling with it myself. Subscribed.
After 'eject' and going thru 'migration' from 4 to 5 it seems the main problems are with paths.

Comment: This will help you in migration: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/9994

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 micro frontends, one appshell (container)

- auth
- container
- dashboard
- marketing

You have to write the config files yourself.

1. for auth (webpack.common.js)

```js
    module.exports = {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.m?js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              options: {
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react', '@babel/preset-env'],
                plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    };
```

(webpack.dev.js)

```js
    const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
    const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');
    const packageJson = require('../package.json');

    const devConfig = {
      mode: 'development',
      output: {
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8082/',
      },
      devServer: {
        port: 8082,
        historyApiFallback: {
          index: 'index.html',
        },
      },
      plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'auth',
          filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './AuthApp': './src/bootstrap',
          },
          shared: packageJson.dependencies,
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: './public/index.html',
        }),
      ],
    };

    module.exports = merge(commonConfig, devConfig);
```

(webpack.prod.js)

```js
    const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
    const ModuleFederationPlugin = require('webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin');
    const packageJson = require('../package.json');
    const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common');

    const prodConfig = {
      mode: 'production',
      output: {
        filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
        publicPath: '/auth/latest/',
      },
      plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
          name: 'auth',
          filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
          exposes: {
            './AuthApp': './src/bootstrap',
          },
          shared: packageJson.dependencies,
        }),
      ],
    };

    module.exports = merge(commonConfig, prodConfig);
```